# Why YouTube still uses H264 "Main" profile for 360p/480p videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube

YouTube uses a number of codecs such as H264, VP9, H263, VP8 etc. I am only looking at the most widely used H264 for now and I've seen across several videos that for 720p and above, YouTube uses 'H264 High profile' and quite rightly but I can't understand why they are still using 'H264 Main profile' for 480p/360p videos.

I understand these resolutions are mostly intended for mobile users on the go with limited bandwidth but as far as I am aware most low end phone can decode 'H264 High profile 480p' with ease so is there any specific reason YouTube still uses 'H264 Main profile' instead of 'H264 High profile' for 480p/360p videos?

Comment: Probably compatibility with devices playing the video.

Comment: Yeah that's the only thing that makes sense but I can't think of any smartphone released in the past 10 years that can't decode H264 High profile @480p.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer on https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Compatibility

Some ancient phones like iPhone 3 and older can't decode High profile.

[Here's the chart for the iOS compatibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3cxt.png)